# Is there a version of moment.js that works with the current Locker Service?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

I want to reliably find the days between two dates in a Lightning Component and https://momentjs.com/ has this capability. **But does it work with the July 2017 Locker Service?**

This [Moment JS format returns function string in Lightning Spring 17](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155107/moment-js-format-returns-function-string-in-lightning-spring-17) could be interpreted as saying that it should.

But it is not listed in this February 2017 [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) and is mentioned in the comments as being a source of some difficulty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just played around with the latest version of [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) , **2.18.1** and seems to play nicely with locker .

Summer 17 whitelisted [InstanceOf](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_instanceof.htm) operator in locker API and that seems to have made Moment.js compatible with locker .

Here are the functions and components that i just tested and seemed to work fine

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.momentJS}"
afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

The Controller class

```
({
afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')); // July 11th 2017, 11:23:19 am
    console.log(moment().format('dddd'));                    // Tuesday
    console.log(moment().format("MMM Do YY"));               // Jul 11th 17
    console.log(moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY'));     // 2017 escaped 2017
    console.log(moment().format());                          // 2017-07-11T11:23:19-04:00
    console.log(moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()); // 6 years ago
    console.log(moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()); // 5 years ago
    console.log(moment().startOf('day').fromNow());        // 11 hours ago
    console.log(moment().endOf('day').fromNow());          // in 13 hours
    console.log(moment().startOf('hour').fromNow());       // 27 minutes ago
    console.log(moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar()); // 07/01/2017
    console.log(moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar());  // Last Wednesday at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar());  // Last Saturday at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar());  // Yesterday at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().calendar());                      // Today at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().add(1, 'days').calendar());       // Tomorrow at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().add(3, 'days').calendar());       // Friday at 11:28 AM
    console.log(moment().add(10, 'days').calendar());      // 07/21/2017
    console.log(moment.locale());         // en
    console.log(moment().format('LT'));   // 11:29 AM
    console.log(moment().format('LTS'));  // 11:29:23 AM
    console.log(moment().format('L'));    // 07/11/2017
    console.log(moment().format('l'));    // 7/11/2017
    console.log(moment().format('LL'));   // July 11, 2017
    console.log(moment().format('ll'));   // Jul 11, 2017
    console.log(moment().format('LLL'));  // July 11, 2017 11:29 AM
    console.log(moment().format('lll'));  // Jul 11, 2017 11:29 AM
    console.log(moment().format('LLLL')); // Tuesday, July 11, 2017 11:29 AM
    console.log(moment().format('llll'));
    var now = moment();
    console.log(now);
    var day = moment(1318781876406);
     console.log(day);
    }
 })
```

The console seems to print all the results as expected

[image]

Here is a sample MomentJs code that works under locker to find difference between dates

```
var now = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
    var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";
    var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
    console.log(s);
```