# Restricting ui:inputDate to take '//'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, date-picker, inputdate

ui:inputDate also takes '01//08//2011'  as ' 01/08/2011'

Is there any way of restricting  ui:inputDate to take any value other than dd/MM/yyyy format when entered manually.

Or

Is there any way to get the exact string entered manually in to  ui:inputDate
so that it can be handled in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no readonly attribute associated to an input element when the ui:inputdata renders, so there is no question of making the ui:date readonly. I was going to recommend lightning:input but you do not get the nice date picker option with lightning:input component

This is what I did,

Downloaded momentJS from here: https://momentjs.com/ and load it into the static resource( do not go for CDN option locker service will not support CDN)

Though this JS library is not officially published as [locker supported third party library](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) , i looked this forum and saw @mohith answer this question: [Is there a version of moment.js that works with the current Locker Service?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183730/is-there-a-version-of-moment-js-that-works-with-the-current-locker-service/183735)

The only close answer I found to validate mm/dd/yyyy format was by using momentJS, all other options will fail you somewhere down the line.

Not to the code

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.momentjs}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.validatedate}" />

    <ui:inputDate aura:id="dateField" label="Birthday" value="2014-01-30" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy" change="{!c.validatedate}"/>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    validatedate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var date_val = component.find("dateField").get("v.value");
        var date_formatter = new Date(date_val);
        if(date_val.includes('//') || !moment(date_formatter, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true).isValid()){
             alert("invalid date please enter in MM/DD/YYYY format");
            component.find("dateField").set("v.value","2014-01-30");
        }
    }
})
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for a quick suggestion Rao, hope it works with further releases as well, will definitely try this and revert. ☺️

Comment: I tried it, its working fine but '//' condition isn't handled here aswell.

Comment: Updated the answer.Try adding date_val.includes('//') in the if condition

Comment: add a check to validate if // or any spl characters your users typically tend to put in for eg: 10-10-2014 etc.. (or) use a regex that will prompt if user enters invalid character using includes() method in javascript https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Comment: @Shri did the fix work for you ?

Comment: yes, it worked but again I'll have to add all unwanted formats in .includes() method, as we cannot use regex with includes. Is there any way of using a regex in this context.